# Determining direction of traffic in road network?

Tags: openstreetmap, linestring, geopandas

I'm working with road segments as LineStrings in GeoPandas, for each segment I would like to determine the direction of travel (they drive on the right).

This information is not encoded, how can I determine it?

I was thinking to query OpenStreetMap, since when I overlay in QGIS I can see this has travel direction information.

Can you think of any other approaches, or guide me in querying OpenStreetMap?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct OSM query for determining traffic direction.

You have to look at the raw data, i.e. the [nodes](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Node) of each [way](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Way) and specifically the order in which these nodes are referenced. This order defines the direction of the way.

However all ways are bidirectional per default unless there is a [`oneway` tag](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:oneway) present. The only exceptions are ways tagged as `highway=motorway` or `junction=roundabout` in which cases `oneway=yes` is implied.